# Map and Render Data from API in ReactJS (Function Components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I'm learning react. Need to map 5 images from the tinyfac.es API in ReactJS (Function Components). Image is being fetched properly (in console) but unable to render it. If possible, please explain the mistake.

Code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

let base_url = `https://tinyfac.es/api/data?limit=50&quality=0`;

function Storyslider() {
  const [Containers, setContainers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(base_url)
      .then((a) => {
        console.log(a.data[0].url);
        setContainers(a.data.results);
      })
      .catch((b) => {
        console.log(Error);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {Containers &&
        Containers.map((Contain, index) => (
          <img
            src={Contain.data[0].url}
            alt={Contain.data[0].gender}
            key={index}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Storyslider;
```

Comment: `a.data.results` is undefined, there's no `results` property in the response. Also, each `Contain` object ***is*** the object with `url` and `gender` properties. there isn't a `data` property on the mapped objects. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `results` key inside `data` object. so That's why, your data are not properly set into `Containers` state.

Here is the working code of yours:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

let base_url = `https://tinyfac.es/api/data?limit=50&quality=0`;

function Storyslider() {
  const [Containers, setContainers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(base_url)
      .then((a) => {
        console.log(a.data);
        setContainers(a.data);
      })
      .catch((b) => {
        console.log(Error);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {Containers &&
        Containers.map((Contain, index) => (
          <img
            src={Contain?.url}
            alt={Contain?.gender}
            key={index}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Storyslider
```

And if you want to render an single image (or first image) from the array you can simply do

```js
{Containers && <img src={Containers[0].url} alt={Containers[0].gender} />}
```

Comment: That is true! I think the author has just confused the data received and the data set to the useState Containers variable

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setContainers(a.data.results)` will result to `container` state being `undefined` as there is no `results` key on the data you are getting back. Here is a simplified working example of your attempt:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

let base_url = `https://tinyfac.es/api/data?limit=50&quality=0`;

function Storyslider() {
  const [containers, setContainers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(base_url)
      .then((a) => {
        setContainers(a.data);
      })
      .catch((b) => {
        console.log(Error);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {containers.map((contain, index) => (
        <img src={contain.url} alt={contain.gender} key={index} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Storyslider;
```

[image: Edit angry-fast-upe615]